# Reading a variable length record mainframe file

Tags: mainframe

I have a mainframe data file in binary format, with variable records. No copybook works in this case, nor do I know end of line. How do I read such a file?

Comment: Show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: what language and what platform are you trying to use ???

Comment: What OS are you using? If off the Mainframe, you should find each record prefixed by four bytes, X'nnnnn0000' where nnnn is a two-byte Big Endian binary indicating the length of the record. The first record will be prefixed by a further four bytes, of similar form, indicating the block-length. Once the block is complete, the next record will also be prefixed by the block control information. You need to look at the data, in hex. If you don't understand it, add a sample to your question along with the answers requested. See the edit link under your question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're reading this file in a COBOL program running on the Mainframe, this is really no problem. COBOL doesn't write null-delimited output. It writes variable length records with the length embedded in the first two bytes of 4-byte prefix area called a (R)ecord (D)escriptor (W)ord, which is NOT included in the record layout copybook.  To read such a record back into another COBOL, you just need a properly coded copybook.